# How do websites recognize visitors?

Tags: web-browser, anonymity

Being more specific, I would like to know which are the possibilities for a webbsite owner to detect whether the same user logs with different accounts, and how to bypass each of them. For example, I already know coockies and I guess it is enough to use the private browsing function of the browser, and to be sure to carry out temporary files removal with some program as CCleaner. That is my first question so I hope it is everything correct. I apologize whether actually it is not. Thanks in advance for every answer and suggestion.

Comment: Welcome to Security.stackexchange. Your question is really broad and hard to read in its current formatting. 

Also can you add how you think this is a security question (there are multiple ways to interpret your question, giving us your goal can help us answer it). Your question also shows you lack important knowledge about how a Computer / Network / Service/ application and Website actually work, I suggest you read a bit more about your issue on the internet.

Comment: Thanks! I have been reading on the internet, but all I could find concerns IP address and coockies. However, I feel like there is something missing. From my point of view this theme cross that of security in that we are exposed to unawared spread of information about our activities online, and that clearly prejudices our privacy. I totally agree on my lack of knowledge about this subject, and I would warmly welcome any source you could recommend to me to deepen it by my own.

Comment: See https://Panopticlick.eff.org

Comment: I saw that site from the question linked by the other user below. Anyway, thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use browser fingerprinting, most browsers are unique in the plugins they use, version of those plugins, screen resolution (if you use your browser in full size) etc.

You can check your browser fingerprint [here](https://panopticlick.eff.org)

Comment: Thank you very much. I have never heard about browser fingerprint before. I will surely look for other material about it!